# TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address" admin.transfer(address(this).balance);

Tags: solidity

```
function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));


        admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

error line ---> admin.transfer(address(this).balance);

can someone help me with this thank you

Answer (score 16):

> *Address literals have the type `address` instead of `address payable`. They can be converted to `address payable` by using an explicit conversion, e.g. `payable(0xdCad3a6d3569DF655070DEd06cb7A1b2Ccd1D3AF)`.*

Source: [Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/080-breaking-changes.html)

What it means, is that since Solidity 0.8, `address` is not `payable` by default. And if you want to send it native currency, you need to cast it to `payable` first.

Example:

```
payable(admin).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

Comment: i tried this one, but have another error instead 
"Expected primary expression payable(admin).transfer(address(this).balance);"

Comment: The "Expected primary expression" error is unrelated to the original issue. Most likely you forgot to put a semicolon or a closing brace somewhere on the previous line.